# Get base64 photo from iOS photo library uri

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm building an app in React Native, and I need to get an image from the Photo Library as base64 using the photo `uri` (e.g. `photos://A2B9B28B-9A3E-4190-BCA0-B11F1E587085/L0/002`). I was originally using the Asset Library but I've updated my app to use the new Photo Library and I'm struggling to get it to work.

My old Asset Library method was:

```
{
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:input];
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullScreenImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]);
    NSString *base64Encoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    callback(@[[NSNull null], base64Encoded]);
  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"that didn't work %@", error);
    callback(@[error]);
  }];
}
```

Comment: after getting image you can convert to base 64

Comment: So I'm getting it using https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework

Comment: You only need to solve the conversion from `photos://A2B9B28B-9A3E-4190-BCA0-B11F1E587085/L0/002` to `NSData` ; the base64 thing is irrelevant and confusing

Comment: How do you did you manage to get the `photos://A2B9B28B-9A3E-4190-BCA0-B11F1E587085/L0/002` in the first place?

Comment: From https://github.com/olofd/react-native-photos-framework. As I've said in the post, I am using React Native, so the goal is to get the image in Javascript as base64; so I'm not sure how you find it irrelevant or confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It is basicly the same as the code you already have, it has just been split into two parts.  First get a `PHAsset` using an id, then get the image from that asset using the `PHImageManager`.

- To get the `PHAsset` from the library use

`[+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options;`

This method is synchronous and immediately returns an array of `PHAsset` but these assets don't contain any image data.

- next use

`[PHImageManager defaultManager]` to get the image.  This is asynchronous like the ALAssetsLibrary method. use `- (PHImageRequestID)requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)asset  options:(PHImageRequestOptions *)options  resultHandler:(void (^)(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;`

The code should be something like this (obviously you have to fill in your error codes and error domain for your application)):

```
PHFetchResult* results = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[input] options:nil];
PHAsset *asset = [results firstObject];
if (asset) {
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        if (imageData){
            NSString *base64Encoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
            callback(@[[NSNull null], base64Encoded]);
        }else{
            NSError* error = info[PHImageErrorKey];
            if (!error) {
                error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"" code:-1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"image not found"}];
            }
            callback(nil, error);

        }
    }];
}else{
    NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"" code:-1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:@"asset not found"}];
    callback(nil, error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the api in PHAsset`+ (PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *)fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)assetURLs options:(nullable PHFetchOptions *)options;`